# Finding the highest value in a dictionary within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, max

There's a task in the beginner course where we have to find the highest value of a certain key in a dictionary.

The values, however, are located within another dictionary. So the format is something like this:

```py
data = {
    'Country1': {2015: 5, 2016: 9, 2017: 2},
    'Country2': {2015: 20, 2016: 10, 2017: 5}
}
```

Of course there's more than two countries there, but essentially I have to find the highest value from a specific year (let's say 2015). Anyone with a quick idea on how to proceed? I've looked at several similar options like `max()` or `lambda` but I'm not sure how they could be used in this particular situation with a list within a list.

Comment: `max(d[2015] for d in data.values())`  Note that this assumes that all countries have a `2015` key -- if that's not a valid assumption, you may want to use something like `.get(2015, -1)` instead of `[2015]`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked!

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```py
data = {
    'Country1': {2015: 5, 2016: 9, 2017: 2},
    'Country2': {2015: 20, 2016: 10, 2017: 5}
}

country_with_max_2015 = max(data, key=lambda k: data[k][2015])
```

In the function `max` the lambda function will get values `'Country1'` and `'Country2'` which can be used to get the value of `'Country1'` from `data` dict and so we can find the value of key `2015` in values of country.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for-loop to iterate through the dictionary of dictionaries
I'll leave it up to you to decide how you want to keep track of the max values you find.

This is for python3, python2 will look a little different

```
data = {'Country1': {2015: 5, 2016: 9, 2017: 2}, 'Country2': {2015: 20, 2016: 10, 2017: 5}}

for country,sub_dict in data.items():
    print(country)
    print(sub_dict)
    
    for year,value in sub_dict.items():
        print(year,value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'Country1': {2015: 5, 2016: 9, 2017: 2}, 'Country2': {2015: 20, 2016: 10, 2017: 5}}

max_val = 0
for _,inner_dict in data.items():
    max_val = max(inner_dict[2015], max_val)
print(max_val)
```

Iterating through the dictionary this way would minimize resource usage especially if you are dealing with a large data set